# spark: difference between writing dataframe to file vs rdd to file in hdfs

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, rdd

Is there a difference between writing dataframes to csv file and writing rdd to csv file in hdfs?

1. I have a scala program that writes rdd to file
2. A pyspark program that writes dataframe to csv file

Both of the jobs runs on the same spark cluster with same memory configs. I have observed that pyspark job is failing with yarn memory overhead issue which can output a 10GB file. But scala program run fine and outputs 40 GB file with no memory issues.

Pyspark internal step where it fails everytime with memory.

```
csv at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0. +details
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:644)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Spark internal step for writing to CSV file

```
runJob at SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78+details
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2087)
org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1096)
```

Am I doing something wrong with writing df to hdfs. Any help would be helpful.

```
 def save_df_in_HDFS(self,spark,application_id, df,output_file):
        #save dataframe as part files in dir and merge
        part_filename = "FINAL_DF"
        seperator = "," 
        intermediate_dir = os.path.join(self.output_dir, application_id, part_filename)
        dst_file = os.path.join(self.output_dir, application_id, output_file)
        df.write.csv(path = intermediate_dir,sep=seperator)
        self.combine_part_files_in_HDFS_dir(spark, intermediate_dir, dst_file, False, True)
```

Scala

```
private def saveRDDToFile(file: String, rdd: RDD[T] forSome {type T}): Unit = {
    val partFile = s"$file-parts"
    rdd.saveAsTextFile(partFile)
    hdfs.delete(file, recursive)
    hdfs.merge(partFile, file)
    hdfs.delete(partFile,true)

  }
```

The problem is at writing data frame to hdfs in CSV(as df writes as partfiles to hdfs first) as I observed that after the pyspark job failed, I dont see any part files.

```
df.write.csv(path = intermediate_dir,sep=seperator)
```

Comment: You need to show some code.

Comment: I have added my code and mentioned the failing step .

Comment: Well you delete at end

Comment: I am only deleting the part files after merging. I still have the merged files in the name of filename that is passed as argument.